# accessing lines from another file and stripping for use in a class

Tags: python, list, readfile, traceback

i have this:

```
class books:
def __init__(self,id,title,author,avaliable):
    self.id=id
    self.title=title
    self.author=author
    self.avaliable=avaliable
def __str__ (self):
    return ('id: '+self.id+'\ntitle:'+self.title+'\nauthor: '+self.author+'\nauthor: '+self.author+'\navaliable:'  + self.avaliable)
def __getitem__(self,i):
    return self.title
with open ('txt.txt','r') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
bo=[]
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    book = line.split(';')
    s = books(book[0],book[1],book[2],book[3])
    bo.append(s)

bo=books()
bo.id=book[0]
bo.title=book[1]
bo.author=book[2]
bo.avaliable=book[3]
```

Trying to access each element of the list as it is being read from the file. At the moment the code is giving the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:/semester 2/programming/coursework/classes with array most   recent.py", line 17, in <module>
    s = books(book[0],book[1],book[2],book[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In my txt document there are four columns that the program should read separately to gain a list of four values for each line. So the program should be able to access each part of the list, but at the moment it is out of range. i was wondering for any hints or tips on how i can change this, Thank you.

The txt file reads as:

```
1;Book_1;Author_1;0
2;Book_2;Author_2;0
3;Book_3;Author_3;0
4;Book_4;Author_4;0 
5;Book_5;Author_5;0 
6;Book_5;Author_5;0
7;Book_7;Author_7;0
8;Book_8;Author_8;0
9;Book_9;Author_9;0
10;Book_10;Author_10;0
```

Comment: Please add the content of your txt.txt file to the question.

Comment: when you run the code in a debugger, what is the content of `book` on the line `s = ...`? BTW, the correct way to split a list into arguments is `books(*book)`

Comment: ['1\\tBook_1\\tAuthor_1\\t0'] is the content returns for book. and thank you

Answer (score 2):

there is a discrepancy between what you say the file contains (`;`) and what the file actually contains when read by your script (`\t` = tab characters, `\\t` = sequence of characters `\` and `t`)

you can either use [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) with the correct delimiter, or if you insist on splitting manually, use:

```
book = line.split('\t')
```

or if the file literally contains `\t`, then use:

```
book = line.split('\\t')
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, i will read into csv file. I tried with the ('\t') and it is still returning the same error, with index out of range.

Comment: eh, try to split by `\\t` then - but I thing there is a bug in how the file is created, it should not contain literal string `\t` as the delimiter... there is another option that the file contains mixed delimiters, in which case you need to edit the file to contain only 1 type of delimiter, search&replace one of them to the correct one